# Access access modifier with reference of variable value in c#

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I went to Access access modifier variable of the other class by the string

went to access access modifier String variable of an other class with the reference of  variable value .
in code simple string variable is access but for access modifier variable it gives  exception .
How Can I access it.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {    
            MyReflectionClass c = new MyReflectionClass();
            var t = c.GetType().GetField("str1").GetValue(c);
            Console.WriteLine(t);
            var test = c.GetType().GetField("str").GetValue(c);
            Console.WriteLine(test);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        public class MyReflectionClass
        {
            public string str { get { return "String with access modifier "; } }
            public string str1 = "string variable";
        }
    }
}
```

OutPut:
string variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str1` is not a field, it's a property. Therefore you need to use `GetProperty` method.

```
var test = c.GetType().  GetProperty("str")  .GetValue(c);
```

It also returns `PropertyInfo` instance instead of `FieldInfo`, but it has the same `GetValue` method.

Comment: Got it Thanks for help

Comment: How Can i use set access modifier to set the value of str

Comment: No, because `str` has no setter ( `set` part). If you add setter, you will be able to do exactly the same but with `SetValue` in the end. `c.GetType().GetProperty("str").SetValue(c, x);`

Comment: Btw, please, don't forget to confirm the answer :)

Comment: It executive perfectly as i needed.thank for you help Me and giving your precious time